# XPath/XQuery: Count node elements and return min count with parent id

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd, xquery

I will give an example to better clarify myself.

Example:

```
<asdf>
    <parentnode id ="1">
           <childnode>
            ...
            </childnode>
            <childnode>
            ...
            </childnode>
    </parentnode>
    <parentnode id ="2">
            <childnode>
            ...
            </childnode>
            <childnode>
            ...
            </childnode>
            <childnode>
            ...
            </childnode>
    </parentnode>
    <parentnode id ="3">
            <childnode>
            ...
            </childnode>
    </parentnode>
</asdf>
```

I need to count all childnodes of all parentnodes and give back the minimum count of childnodes of the given parentnode with its id.

For this example the solution would be:

```
<parentnode id="3" amount="1"/>
```

I don't really know where to begin. Do I have to count distinct elements in a for loop or is this also possible with an Xpath expression ?
I'm not sure if this is the right direction:

```
let $a := fn:doc('asdf.xml')/asdf/*
 return 
for $z in distinct-values($a/name() = childnode )
 order by count($z) ascending
 return $z)[1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Sort those `parentnode` elements by the `count()` of the `childnode`
- From that sorted sequence, select the first, which is the one with the least amount of `childnode` elements
- then construct an element using the [computed element constructor](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xquery-31-20170321/#id-computedElements) using the `name()` of the `$least-children` element, copying any of it's attributes, and then creating the `@amount` attribute using a [computed attribute constructor](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xquery-31-20170321/#id-computedAttributes) assigning it the value of the `count()` of it's `childnode` elements

.

```
let $least-children := 
  (for $parent in $a
   order by count($parent/childnode) ascending
   return $parent)[1]

return
  element {$least-children/name()} { 
    $least-children/@*, 
    attribute {"amount"} { count($least-children/childnode)} 
  }
```

Comment: Thank you but could you elaborate your sample solution ?

Comment: Another question. Is it possible to alter the xquery for documents with an unknown document structure ? I mean is there a more general solution where you don't know the element names of the parent nodes and child nodes and you start from the highest node possible ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. If you weren't sure of the names of the elements, but just knew that `/*/*` were the "parent" elements that you wanted to compute for, and wanted to count it's child elements? Replace `childnode` with `*` in each of the places that it occurs in the answer and it should still work. i.e. `order by count($parent/*) ascending` and `attribute {"amount"} { count($least-children/*)} `

Answer (score 1):

Another way to identify the minimum count is to use the `min` function:

```
let $parents := asdf/parentnode,
    $counts := $parents/count(childnode),
    $min := min($counts),
    $parent := $parents[index-of($counts, $min)]
return 
    <parentnode id="{$parent/@id}" amount="{$min}"/>
```